# Loading JSON model using three.js - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm trying to load a model that I created in blender using the three.js exporter addon. However I'm a reoccurring error even if I change around the loading property, and I would like to know the correct way to format it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
     </head>
<body>
 <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
 <script src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>

 <script>
 // Setup a new scene
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();

 // Setup the camera
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
 camera.position.z = 5;
 camera.position.y = 1;

 // Setup the renderer
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


 // Add the lights
 var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
 scene.add(ambientLight);

 var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFDD );
 light.position.set( -15, 10, 15 );
 scene.add( light );

 // Models
 var model;
 var theaterModel;

 // instantiate a loader
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

 // load a resource
 loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'models/Theater-of-PalmyraNEW.json',
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( object );
    }
 );

 function render() {
         camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
         camera.position.y += ( - mouseY + 200 - camera.position.y ) * .05;
         camera.lookAt( scene.position );
         renderer.render( scene, camera );
     }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error of which is, uncaught Type Errors in the three.js file and three.min.js files.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at three.min.js:658
    at Jd.parse (three.min.js:661)
    at three.min.js:657
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.min.js:605)
```

This may just be a simple error that I'm not seeing - and that I've seen other's having problems with this.